# unable to edit bash prompt

Tags: macos, mac, bash, terminal

I'm on Mac OSX and trying to test out some new prompt settings in terminal. Here's my setup

```
$ echo $PS1
$ \h:\W \u\$
```

This prompt works fine. But if I type

```
$ export $PS1="test"
```

I get the following errors

```
-bash: export: `\h:\W': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `\u\$': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `=test': not a valid identifier
```

Any ideas on why this is happening? I don't have a .bashrc file but I do have an /etc/bashrc file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$` is only needed when reading the current value.

```
export PS1="test"
```

Comment: Yes. You need the `$` in a variable to *read* its value. Example: `$PS1`. But you do not use a `$` when *setting* its value. Example: `PS1`.

Answer (score 3):

Your export command expanded the prompt variable and tried to export the string "\h:\W \u\".  You got an error message because those three substrings don't exist as variable names.  As Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams indicated, you need to drop the leading "$" in the export command, which will then export the PROMPT variable as you intended.
Brief version: By specifying the PROMPT to be expanded, the command tried to export the wrong thing.